# Unity Hub doesn't show new install

Tags: unity3d

I just installed Unity 2020.3.30f1 and while it shows in Control panel,
[image: Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features]
It doesn't show in the unity hub `Installs` tab.
[image: Unity Hub > Installs > All]
What's going on?

I'm using:
Windows 10 Home
Unity Hub 3.0.1
Unity 2020.3.30f1

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2020.3.30f1 started showing in Unity Hub after I ran it once. I don't know if this was a ug, or if it's meant to be like that, but problem solved.

Comment: Right now this post lacks clear info on what you did to solve the problem. Please expand and clarify this post to improve it.